# Undefined ajax response when page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have a script, below, and when the page loads I get an error message: `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`, so I researched the error and found that the AJAX request wasn't executed. If I execute the same code in the browser console, the script works fine. What's wrong with my code?

```
<script>

function getCitiesList() {
  var country_id = '189';
  return $.ajax({
    type: 'get',//тип запроса: get,post либо head
    url: '/countries/' + country_id + '/cities' + "&authenticity_token=" + AUTH_TOKEN,
  });
}

function getCitiesList2() {
  var bla = getCitiesList();
  console.log(bla['responseJSON']);
  var i = 0;
  var data = [];
  while (i < bla['responseJSON'].length) {
    data[i] = {};
    data[i]['id'] = bla['responseJSON'][i]['id'];
    data[i]['text'] = bla['responseJSON'][i]['title'];
    i++;
  }
  console.log(data);
}


$('#city').select2({
  data: getCitiesList2(),
  width: "100%"
});

</script>
```

Comment: What it prints with -console.log(bla['responseJSON']),I assume your response comes later and the code in getCitiesList2() executes first(without response)

Comment: Is there suppose to be a trailing comma after `AUTH_TOKEN`? In `url: '/countries/' + country_id + '/cities' + "&authenticity_token=" + AUTH_TOKEN,`.

Answer (score 0):

Since JavaScript is asynchronous language, it just keeps running and doesn't wait for AJAX to return result.

In your code, the first line of `getCitiesList2` function assigns the return value of an AJAX call. The AJAX returns **later**, and `var bla` doesn't yet have the response. To solve this, you can pass a callback to your AJAX function `getCitiesList` and execute it on AJAX success.

```
function getCitiesList(callback) {
  var country_id = '189';
  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',//тип запроса: get,post либо head
    url: '/countries/' + country_id + '/cities' + "&authenticity_token=" + AUTH_TOKEN,
    success: function(result) {
      callback(result);
    }
  });
}

function getCitiesList2() {
  getCitiesList(function(result) {
    var i = 0;
    var data = [];
    while (i < result['responseJSON'].length) {
      data[i] = {};
      data[i]['id'] = result['responseJSON'][i]['id'];
      data[i]['text'] = result['responseJSON'][i]['title'];
      i++;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `console.log(bla['responseJSON']);` in `getCitiesList2` is executed before the ajax response is received. And after `var bla = getCitiesList();` assignment, `bla` basically holds a [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). All you need to do is to assign a callback function that is going to be executed once the ajax call returns.

```
<script>

function getCitiesList() {
  var country_id = '189';
  return $.ajax({
    type: 'get',//тип запроса: get,post либо head
    url: '/countries/' + country_id + '/cities' + "&authenticity_token=" + AUTH_TOKEN,
  }).done(function(data){         
     $('#city').select2({
       data: processCitiesResponse(data),
       width: "100%"
     });
  });
}

function processCitiesResponse(data)
{
     console.log(data);
     var i = 0;
     var options = [];
     while (i < data.responseJSON.length) {
        options[i] = {};
        options[i].id = data.responseJSON[i].id;
        options[i].text = data.responseJSON[i].title;
        i++;
     }
     console.log(options );
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

first and second answer doesn't help, the same problem.

This work:

```
<script>
                              var AUTH_TOKEN = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
                              function Blabla(){
                                var country_id = '189';
                                $.ajax({
                                  type: 'get',
                                  url: '/countries/' + country_id + '/cities' + "&authenticity_token=" + AUTH_TOKEN,
                                  success: function(bla){
                                    var i = 0;
                                    var data = [];
                                    while (i < bla.length) {
                                      data[i] = {};
                                      data[i]['id'] = bla[i]['id'];
                                      data[i]['text'] = bla[i]['title'];
                                      i++;
                                    }
                                    $('#city').select2({
                                      data: data,
                                      width: "100%"
                                    });
                                  }
                                });
                              }
                              Blabla();
                          </script>
```